# Photoshop how to create a bounded visibility layer?

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs6, layers

I don't know what the name of what I am trying to achieve is. A psd file came my way, and I was able to put an image layer below the type of layer I am trying to figure out how to do (and the name of it too), and only a section of the image was visible.

Even if the image is larger that the area of the layer I am investigating, only a certain area of the image is visible.

This is difficult to explain so I made a video of my screen as I moved the image layer below the mysterious layer. Please view video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KWMuo9QKLVM

Question, what is the name of the layer that allows me to put an image layer below of it (in the layers order) and make only a certain area visible?

How can I create this type of layer?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called clipping mask. [Here](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/revealing-layers-clipping-masks.html) is a great guide that shows you how to do it